# Adding an empty value to a dropdown list that is inside a panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down list thats inside a panel that I am trying to populate in the code behind.

I have the code (part of it) in aspx as follows :

```
    <asp:panel id="editPanel" runat="server">
         // ..... more code.... 
         <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlTest" ></asp:DropDownList>
         // .. more code....
    </asp:panel>
```

In the code behind :

```
ddlTest.DataSource = ds;
        ddlTest.DataTextField = "materialType";
        ddlTest.DataValueField = "materialType";
        ddlTest.DataBind();
        ddlTest.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));
```

But it never adds the blank item.

Now if I put the drop down list outside of the panel, then it does work.

Why does it not work when its inside a panel?

Comment: add the empty value in the dataset, if `ds` is dataset

Comment: @Nobody yes that is an option.. i understand.. But i am trying to understand why it doesn't work... :)

Comment: because its databound now `ddlTest.DataBind();` . so unless you modify its source `ddlTest.DataSource = ds;` you can't do anything about it.

Comment: but if the ddl is outside of the panel, it does work. so what changed simply because its inside a panel ?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't answer that. somebody more knowledgeable than me might answer you why that's happening. Kindly wait. or google for the same in the meanwhile :)

Comment: Works just fine, an empty item is added even inside the Panel.

Comment: It would be kind of you, if u could tag me when you find the answer. It'd be good to learn something I think I should know about.

Comment: @Nobody i sure will :)

Comment: @VDWWD it doesn't work for me like that..

Comment: @Nobody .. one work around I found is to add an empty row to the table and then bind it : DataRow newRow = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
        newRow["materialType"] = "";
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 0);

Comment: I was pointing towards the same thing. To add a row to the datatable in the `ds` then bind it. But not by approaching the way you do. Glad you found a way for it! :) and thanks for the tag. Will experiment on it later on.

Comment: Np. Still doesn't answer the original question though.. I found out that there is a panel.databind() being called inside the codebehind.. so i am thinking it has to do something ..